# Why will some text fade in WPF but some will Not

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am creating a WPF app in visual studio using c#. I am trying to make text fade from one color to another. Some of the text will change color but some just stays one singular color. The code appears to be exactly the same so I do not know what I am doing wrong.

```
 // This is the working code
UserControl x:Class="MiniBiotronWPF2.Home"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MiniBiotronWPF2"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="510" d:DesignWidth="650">
    <Grid>

        <TextBlock
  x:Name="MyChangingColorText"
  Margin="41,123,10,261" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Welcome to Mini Biotron">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="MySolidColorBrush" Color="White"/>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
            <TextBlock.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBrush"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
            From="#FF383535" To="White" Duration="0:0:3"
            AutoReverse="false" RepeatBehavior="0:0:3" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock
  x:Name="MyChangingColorText1"
  Margin="188,220,156,168" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Beta Edition">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="MySolidColorBrush1" Color="White"/>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
            <TextBlock.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBrush1"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
            From="#FF383535" To="White" Duration="0:0:3"
            AutoReverse="false" RepeatBehavior="0:0:3" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>
```

//This is the rest of the program which does not fade

```
<TextBlock
  x:Name="MyChangingColorText2"
  Margin="200,385,255,0" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Text=" Created by Lane Whitten ">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="MySolidColorBrush2" Color="White"/>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
            <TextBlock.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBrush1"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
            From="#FF383535" To="White" Duration="0:0:3"
            AutoReverse="false" RepeatBehavior="0:0:3" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock
  x:Name="MyChangingColorText3"
  Margin="200,432,25,0" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Text=" Copyright © 2018 UW BIOTRON">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="MySolidColorBrush3" Color="White"/>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
            <TextBlock.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBrush1"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
            From="#FF383535" To="White" Duration="0:0:3"
            AutoReverse="false" RepeatBehavior="0:0:3" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>

        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock
  x:Name="MyChangingColorText4"
  Margin="71,409,25,0" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Text=" For questions, concerns or to request new features contact: lanewhitten14@gmail.com ">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="MySolidColorBrush4" Color="White"/>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
            <TextBlock.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBrush"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
            From="#FF383535" To="White" Duration="0:0:3"
            AutoReverse="false" RepeatBehavior="0:0:3" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>



    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your non-working `TextBlock` are targeting to **SolidColorBrush1** which should be **MySolidColorBrush2**,**MySolidColorBrush3**....

Instead define a Style as Resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBrush">Black</SolidColorBrush>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextBrush}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation                                
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                            From="#FF383535" To="White" Duration="0:0:3"
                            AutoReverse="false" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then just define Textblock in the same window:

```
 <TextBlock Text="Text1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example that doesn't work, take a look at

```
Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBrush1"
```

This Textblock element can't find `MySolidColorBrush1` so it doesn't work correctly. You should put brushes in your UserControl.Resources so that every element in this UserControl can find the Brush resource.